# Shadowbox in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, flv, shadowbox

I'm opening a .flv in shadowbox, works fine in Firefox, but opens below the overlay in IE.  I looked on their site, and double checked the `<doctype>`.  That's fine, but still have the problem.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being a Fusebox/ColdFusion issue.  Some custom tags I'm using placed HTML comments at the top of every page, before the doctype declartion.  I suppressed those from the output (using `<cfsilent>`) and all is well.  **The doctype needs to be strict, and has to be the first item of your page.**

Answer (score 0):

On shadowbox_overlay set position: absolute

Comment: can you be a little more specific?  I added a <style> tag with that decleration and it didn't work.  Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">` OK

`<!--DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">-->` CLOSE or DELETE

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` CHANGE
```